# Cypress is not working well it will automatically close after some time

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have to run some test cases i am run the command npx cypress open from command line
its open the cypress test runner but after some time it gets automatically closed.
cypress version 9.7.0

I got this error when test runner is closed

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
at TLSWrap.onerror (node:_tls_wrap:411:27)